# How to convert tabs only between words of a sentense in a text or tsv file to spaces using bash script

Tags: bash, bash4

I have a text or tsv file of below contents :

**FILE : sample_txt.txt :**

```
    1   0x0001  ram_var2    int                                                                                                 
                                            test.c  func2   63      Y                                               "The expression '          ram_var2=e;
   ' at line no 63 has been modified in file test.c. Hence all read checks are applied
 "                                                      test.c  func2   68      Y   
                                        "The expression '           h=ram_var2;' at line no 68 has been modified in file test.c. Hence all read checks are applied
```

Now i want to remove all the unnecessary tabs between the words or the complete sentence. 
For example i want the sentence should look like :

```
"The expression 'ram_var2=e; ' at line no 63 has been modified in file test.c. Hence all read checks are applied"
```

How to achieve this using Linux bash script. Actually the script should be able to take care of all such tabs between all the sentences in the script and it also should take care that other tabs should not get affected. How to achieve this. Please guide me on this. I am very new to the bash scripting. Any help will be definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/\t/ /g" $1
```

This tells sed to look for tab characters, and replace all of them with spaces.

Comment: thanks for this reply. But i want to replace the tabs only between all the double quotes i.e " " in the file and not others. Can you please give the solution for that. It would be very helpful for me. Please..

Comment: Waiting for your reply Tom.

Comment: i got a solution on this by sudo_O once. that is : awk '{$1=$1}1' ORS=' ' check_1.xls | grep -o '"[^"]*"'
 But i prints only the lines between the double quotes and doesn't print all the contents of the file.

Comment: For that, you'll need to learn how to create regular expressions. Your original question does not mention that you are only interested in performing these transformations on string literals. Both awk and sed can be used to this effect.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the reply. Can you guide me on creating the regular expression for this particular case. l